# How to estimate a VAR model with some of its parameters being fixed?

Tags: regression, time-series, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, feature-selection

Saying, I have a VAR model
$$
y_{1,t}=\mathbf{A}^T\mathbf{y}_{t-1}
$$
where $\mathbf{A}^T=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ and $\mathbf{y}_{t-1}=(y_{1,t-1},y_{2,t-1},\dots,y_{n,t-1})^T$.

I know there are many algorithms (closed-form or iterative ones) to estimate the parameter $\mathbf{A}$. But how to efficiently estimate $\mathbf{A}$ if some of the parameters are already known or have to be fixed. For example, if I know $a_1=0, a_8=0.1,a_{20}=0.5$, how can I estimate other parameters while keeping these three parameters unchanged?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/systemfit/vignettes/systemfit.pdf, in particular Section 2.3

Comment: I think the easiest approach would be to write your own likelihood function for the VAR with the constraints you have in mind and enter it into an optimization algorithm....like optim in r or fmincon in matlab.  Would you be open to something along those lines?